# Implementing FNV hash in swift

Tags: algorithm, hash, swift

I am trying to implement a version of FNV hash in swift. Here it is in Objective-C:

```
+ (uint32_t)hash:(uint8_t *)a length:(uint32_t)length
{
    uint8_t *p;
    uint32_t x;

    p = a;
    x = *p << 7;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        x = (1000003 * x) ^ *p++;
        x ^= length;
    }
    if (x == -1) {
        x = -2;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Here is my attempt at porting it to swift:

```
func hashFNV(data: UInt8[]) -> UInt32 {
    var x = data[0] << 7

    for byte in data {
        x *= 1000003
        x ^= byte
        x ^= data.count
    }
    if x == -1 {
        x = -2
    }
    return x
}
```

It compiles but results in an error at runtime:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Same error when I try in the playground:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
* thread #1: tid = 0x619fa, 0x000000010d119aad, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010d119aad
    frame #1: 0x0000000100204880 libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`value witness table for Swift.Int + 160
```

I thought that maybe it was related to the overflow, but the following code also fails with the same error:

```
func hashFNV(data: UInt8[]) -> UInt32 {
    var x = UInt32(data[0]) << 7

    for byte in data {
        x = 1000003 &* x
        x ^= byte
        x ^= data.count
    }
    if x == -1 {
        x = -2
    }
    return x
}
```

EDIT:

Actually, shouldn't the fact that I am trying to assign -2 to x result in a compile error? I thought swift won't implicitly cast from what looks like Int (-2) to UInt32 (x).

Same with the `x ^= byte` line. `byte` should be UInt8 and x is UInt32.

EDIT 2:

This was a compile error (see comments below).

Fixed the compile error, still fails at runtime:

```
func hashFNV(data: UInt8[]) -> UInt32 {
    var x = Int(data[0]) << 7

    for byte in data {
        x = 1000003 &* x
        x ^= Int(byte)
        x ^= data.count
    }
    if x == -1 {
        x = -2
    }
    return UInt32(x)
}
```

Comment: "if x == -1" doesn't even make sense, if `x` is supposed to be unsigned.

Comment: @jtbandes yeah I just noticed that. Shouldn't that be a compile error? I thought swift doesn't do implicit casting.

Comment: It is a compile error for me. I'm not sure what you're doing differently...

Comment: @jtbandes I found out why it wasn't failing to compile for me: This code is in a framework, and the current build target is the app that uses it, so it doesn't show compile errors in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an implementation, here is mine. It is built much like the regular default `Hasher` from the standard lib.

```
struct HasherFNV1a {

    private var hash: UInt = 14_695_981_039_346_656_037
    private let prime: UInt = 1_099_511_628_211

    mutating func combine<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S) where S.Element == UInt8 {
        for byte in sequence {
            hash ^= UInt(byte)
            hash = hash &* prime
        }
    }

    func finalize() -> Int {
        Int(truncatingIfNeeded: hash)
    }
}

extension HasherFNV1a {

    mutating func combine(_ string: String) {
        combine(string.utf8)
    }

    mutating func combine(_ bool: Bool) {
        combine(CollectionOfOne(bool ? 1 : 0))
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is `FNV1a`, if you truly need `FNV1` you can just switch the 2 lines in the loop around.

Answer (score -1):

I found [this GPL Swift implementation](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/Swift-FNV-Hash):

```
//
// FNVHash.swift
//
// A Swift implementation of the Fowler–Noll–Vo (FNV) hash function
// See http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/
//
// Created by Mauricio Santos on 3/9/15.
import Foundation
// MARK:- Constants
private struct Constants {
// FNV parameters
#if arch(arm64) || arch(x86_64) // 64-bit
static let OffsetBasis: UInt = 14695981039346656037
static let FNVPrime: UInt = 1099511628211
#else // 32-bit
static let OffsetBasis: UInt = 2166136261
static let FNVPrime: UInt = 16777619
#endif
}
// MARK:- Public API
/// Calculates FNV-1 hash from a raw byte array.
public func fnv1(bytes: [UInt8]) -> UInt {
var hash = Constants.OffsetBasis
for byte in bytes {
hash = hash &* Constants.FNVPrime // &* means multiply with overflow
hash ^= UInt(byte)
}
return hash
}
/// Calculates FNV-1a hash from a raw byte array.
public func fnv1a(bytes: [UInt8]) -> UInt {
var hash = Constants.OffsetBasis
for byte in bytes {
hash ^= UInt(byte)
hash = hash &* Constants.FNVPrime
}
return hash
}
/// Calculates FNV-1 hash from a String using it's UTF8 representation.
public func fnv1(str: String) -> UInt {
return fnv1(bytesFromString(str))
}
/// Calculates FNV-1a hash from a String using it's UTF8 representation.
public func fnv1a(str: String) -> UInt {
return fnv1a(bytesFromString(str))
}
/// Calculates FNV-1 hash from an integer type.
public func fnv1<T: IntegerType>(value: T) -> UInt {
return fnv1(bytesFromNumber(value))
}
/// Calculates FNV-1a hash from an integer type.
public func fnv1a<T: IntegerType>(value: T) -> UInt {
return fnv1a(bytesFromNumber(value))
}
/// Calculates FNV-1 hash from a floating point type.
public func fnv1<T: FloatingPointType>(value: T) -> UInt {
return fnv1(bytesFromNumber(value))
}
/// Calculates FNV-1a hash from a floating point type.
public func fnv1a<T: FloatingPointType>(value: T) -> UInt {
return fnv1a(bytesFromNumber(value))
}
// MARK:- Private helper functions
private func bytesFromString(str: String) -> [UInt8] {
var byteArray = [UInt8]()
for codeUnit in str.utf8 {
byteArray.append(codeUnit)
}
return byteArray
}
private func bytesFromNumber<T>(var value: T) -> [UInt8] {
return withUnsafePointer(&value) {
Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: UnsafePointer<UInt8>($0), count: sizeof(T)))
}
}
```